# How to find the max value within a column which is a certain distance of the current row in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'input':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
                                   11,12,13,14,15,14.5,
                                   13.5,12.5,11.5,10.5,
                                   9.5,8.5,7.5,6.5,5.5,
                                   4.5,3.5,2.5,1.5,0.5]})
```

I would like to add a column to the right of the 'input' column which has the maximum value within the 'input' series which is found within 3 rows of the current row. For the example data above, the 'max' column would end up looking like this:

```
data['max'] = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
               14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,14.5,13.5,12.5,
               11.5,10.5,9.5,8.5,7.5,6.5,5.5,4.5,3.5]
```

Now I know that I can iterate through the 'input' series one row at a time, and find the max within my 3 row range that way, but I'm hoping there might be a better way to do it, preferably as a single (or maybe a couple) array operations. Ultimately I also need to add a 'min' column as well, but we can ignore that for now for the sake of simplicity.

So with that background, can this be done more cleanly or efficiently than just by iterating over the rows? My data set is on the order of millions of rows, so efficiency is rather important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas-dataframe-rolling) with `center=` parameter:

```py
data['max_new'] = data['input'].rolling(window=7, min_periods=1, center=True).max()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
    input   max  max_new
0     1.0   4.0      4.0
1     2.0   5.0      5.0
2     3.0   6.0      6.0
3     4.0   7.0      7.0
4     5.0   8.0      8.0
5     6.0   9.0      9.0
6     7.0  10.0     10.0
7     8.0  11.0     11.0
8     9.0  12.0     12.0
9    10.0  13.0     13.0
10   11.0  14.0     14.0
11   12.0  15.0     15.0
12   13.0  15.0     15.0
13   14.0  15.0     15.0
14   15.0  15.0     15.0
15   14.5  15.0     15.0
16   13.5  15.0     15.0
17   12.5  15.0     15.0
18   11.5  14.5     14.5
19   10.5  13.5     13.5
20    9.5  12.5     12.5
21    8.5  11.5     11.5
22    7.5  10.5     10.5
23    6.5   9.5      9.5
24    5.5   8.5      8.5
25    4.5   7.5      7.5
26    3.5   6.5      6.5
27    2.5   5.5      5.5
28    1.5   4.5      4.5
29    0.5   3.5      3.5
```